# How to read last night errors or warning logs from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We had an issue last night our sql server databases. How to read those logs from SQL Server database? Will those errors available in Database transaction log file?

Please point me to find out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of errors that you received...  but this MSDN article describes how to [view the Sql Server Error Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> By default, the error log is located at Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n files.